# Unit Tests return properties as <Closure: () => Type> and fail consistently

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, stacked

I am just starting my unit testing, and finding an issue where returning a property from a Service Class is returning as a blank Closure, rather than returning the actual value.

[image]

It's like this for every property I've tried to return from this class, whether it's a regular property, a getter, and whether or not I assign a default value. It shows the result as:

```
Expected: <X>
Actual: Closure: () => Type>
```

Currently, I'm trying to return the value for loggedInUser in my TestService class, and verify that it's set to null. I know it's set to null, because I set that as a default value, and I have a `print()` statement right before my `expect()` statement, that does show the loggedInUser to be null.

Is there anything in this class that could be causing this? (note: I'm using the stacked package from FilledStacks for dependency injection, and this is a service that gets injected in my locator).

Here is the test in question:

```
void main() {
  group('TestService Tests -', () {
    TestService sut;

    setUp(() {
      registerServices();
    });

    tearDown(() {
      unregisterServices();
    });
    group('Initialize -', () {
      test('Determine authpage type when not logged in', () async {
        sut = TestService();
        User? result = sut.loggedInUser;
        print('Sut is equal to ${sut.loggedInUser}');

        expect(() => result, null);
      });
```

And here is the test service (note: I don't have specific initialization code in here either). There's a function that runs immediately when this service first gets used in production that initializes the `firstTimeUsingApp` late bool property.

```
class TestService {
  final AuthenticationService _firebaseAuth = locator<AuthenticationService>();
  final SharedPreferencesService _prefs = locator<SharedPreferencesService>();
  final Logger _log = getLogger('LoginAndUserService');

  User? _loggedInUser = null;
  User? get loggedInUser => _loggedInUser;
  late bool _firstTimeUsingApp;
  bool? get firstTimeUsingApp => _firstTimeUsingApp;
  LoginStatus _currentLoginStatus = LoginStatus.notInitialized;
  LoginStatus get currentLoginStatus => _currentLoginStatus;
```

Comment: But why are you passing `() => result` instead of just `result`? Have you looked at the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-test_api_expect/expect.html)?

Comment: Yup - that was the issue. I thought I had caught all my potential bonehead mistakes on this one, but that's it. Thanks for the help!